# All web browsers cause this computer, regardless of what they're doing

Tags: ssd

all;

I have a rather vexing problem. I've done my homework and Googled around for an answer. This problem appears to have many potential causes. Having tried many permutations of fixes and adding, reconfiguring, purging and otherwise manhandling the software has gotten me nowhere (well, I got it back to the way it was before I started - at least I have a relatively clean slate by now). So now, completely fed up with it, I'm posing the problem to the community and asking for ideas.

Problem: On this machine, web browsers frequently cause the system to lock up. Sometimes waiting it out eventually gets just enough response to run a quick killall, but more commonly the machine is so badly stuck that I have to cut the power and restart. Some particulars:

1. Dell Latitude E5500, Core 2 Duo T7250, 3GB RAM, an SSD - hardly a hot rod, but clearly should be enough to run Linux with a browser, a mail client and an IM system running (pretty much all I use it for).
2. So far, the hardware checks out - the wifi stability sucks, but that's par for machines of this type and everything else I've thought of looks solid. I'm doubtful it's an electronic issue.
3. Kubuntu 14.04 LTS - last dist-upgrade was last night.
4. Pidgin runs just fine. Thunderbird (with Lightning and IMAPing to my mail server) can get a little creaky at times, but not too much.
5. I've tried a bunch of current browsers: Chrome, Chromium, two different builds of Firefox, and Tor. All of them exhibit the same behavior.

What happens is this; if I have more than a trivial number of tabs open - in any of the browsers I've tested - the system will suddenly start banging its head against a wall.

Screen refre``sh is better measured in frames per minute rather than per second.

The hard drive activity light comes on and is almost completely solid - if you look closely it's actually flashing at a rate that's just within the human visual threshold. This part *really* confuses me - I recently installed a brand-new SATA SSD; it's exhibiting the same behavior. I am, at this point, very confused.

Comment: Not enough RAM if you open too many tabs. Obvious. Swapping.

Comment: 3G RAM with how much swap? In `terminal` show me the output of `free -h` and `swapon`. Edit this output into your question please. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info.

Answer (score 0):

A likely reason maybe that the system is actively swapping data when you open several applications and tabs on browser. To check the swap space in your computer you should open terminal (using `Ctrl+Alt+T`) and the typing in `free -h`. The output will be as following.

```
          total       used       free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       1.8G       1.2G       295M        135M        302M        261M
Swap:      1.9G        29M       1.9G
```

The `Swap` row tell about how much `swap` space is there and how much is being used. You can check then your system becomes slow.

---

If Swap space is filled up, but memory is still available, then,

1.) You can try to reduce the value of parameter which makes the system to swap. Default value is 60, which makes the system to swap quite fast. For systems with less RAM, a good value should be 10 or small.

To change the swappiness, open the terminal by `Ctrl+Alt+T`, then open the `/etc/sysctl.conf`  file using sudo access, for example,

`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

and add the following line at the end of the file,

`vm.swappiness = 6`

Save the file and then restart the system. Check if any improvement is seen.

---

If you do not want to restart, you can try to run,

`sysctl vm.swappiness=6`

in the terminal.

Comment: Best to check IF the user has swap space defined/enabled BEFORE trying to change vm.swappiness.

Comment: @heynnema  I agree.

Comment: You may wish to update/edit your answer then :-)